Upload CSV to google cloud query
Please help me. I want to upload csv to google cloud query but there is error :
Error while reading data, error message: Unable to parse; line_number: 37678 byte_offset_to_start_of_line: 16564658 column_index: 1 column_name: "author_id" column_type: INT64 value: "dummyUser"
Thank you
check the Unknown values but still error
